# is editing a text file makes the CPU run in the user mode?

Tags: operating-system

I don't fully understand the difference between instructions that run in kernel or user mode.

can you give me examples?

Also is editing a text file makes the CPU run in the user mode or kernel mode?

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle, ALL instructions run in both kernel mode and user mode. A small subset of of instructions run only in kernel mode. The latter are typically instructions for modifying special purpose registers, such as those that define the process page tables and those that switch process contexts.

If you edit a text file, you will run in both user mode and kernel mode.